# Trying to retrieve data from POST petition

Tags: html, django

I'm new to HTML and I've got this sort of quiz which displays one question and multiple answers to the user. Now I'm trying to retrieve which answers the user selected but I haven't been able to do so.
This is the code of the answers of the quiz:

```
<form action="/reto_resultado/{{ clave_primaria }}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for respuesta in respuestas %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="respuesta" id="respuesta{{ forloop.counter }}"><label class="form-check-label" for="respuesta{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ respuesta.texto }}</label></div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
<div class="buttons"><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" role="button" style="background-color: rgb(52,58,64);"></form>
```

This is the code in which I try to retrive those answers:

```
respuesta_marcada = request.POST.get('respuesta', '')
```

The problem is that I only get 'None' or 'on', which means nothing for me.

Comment: "on" is True and "None" is False.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your inputs a value. Assuming the respuesta is a model instance with a pk, you could do:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" value="{{ respuesta.pk }}" name="respuesta" id="respuesta{{ forloop.counter }}">
```

and then `request.POST.getlist('respuesta')` will get you a list of the selected IDs.